# Cypress uploadfile failed with 100MB video file in docker cypress/included:4.4.0 but successful locally

Tags: docker, file-upload, cypress

I am trying to upload a video file through a web app's form that will first analyse the duration, resolution and FPS of the video. With this information, the video file will then be sent to back end server upon clicking a submit button.

I tried to upload a 100MB video file using the following way:

The following is the uploadFile cypress command in support/commands.js.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('uploadFile', { prevSubject: true }, (subject, fileName, fileType = '') => {
  cy.fixture(fileName,'base64', { timeout: 20000 }).then(content => {
    console.log(fileName, content)
    return Cypress.Blob.base64StringToBlob(content, fileType).then(blob => {
      const fileInput = subject[0];
      const testFile = new File([blob], fileName, {type: fileType});
      const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();

      dataTransfer.items.add(testFile);
      fileInput.files = dataTransfer.files;
      console.log(fileInput, testFile, dataTransfer); 
      cy.wrap(subject).trigger('change', { force: true });
    });
  });

});
```

In the spec.js

```
cy.get('input[type=file]').uploadFile('largeVideo.mp4', 'video/mp4');
```

Cypress uploadfile failed with 100MB video file in docker cypress/included:4.4.0 yet when running locally with `npx cypress run`, the video file managed to upload successfully.

The error from cypress was

```
CypressError: cy.fixture() timed out waiting 200000ms to receive a fixture. No fixture was ever sent by the server.
```

**Details**

cypress version 4.4.0

chrome version 80.0.3987.116

node version 12.13.0

What is the difference between local cypress and docker version that causes this to happen?

Comment: Maybe your docker container doesn't have enough disk space or memory to store the file. What's the memory allocated to your container ? Maybe you should try to allocate more or maybe use a volume to store the file.

Comment: I didn't set any memory configuration for the docker container so it is using the docker default value. I can't mount a volume in my case as I am using a Jenkins container to run the container. The mounting didn't work so I copy the entire directory during docker build

Comment: i just checked. The memory allocated to the cypress container is about 31 GB.

Comment: @seetfeifang did you fix your issue, I am seeing the same behavior with My GitHub action

Comment: No. I decided to put it on hold as I have no idea how else I can solve this (ps. I am a beginner in cypress and docker). Please do update me if you happen to find out why?

Comment: @seetfeifang increasing `responseTimeout` fix my issue